# Where are the pop-up windows and branching in HTML documents?

Tags: liclipse

I am testing LiClipse 6.1.0 and I am trying to configure HTML documents as python documents; help pop-ups while writing code and branching for drop-down code blocks (+)

[image: Branch_WindowHelp_python]

[image: Branch_WindowHelp_HTML]

but I don't see the necessary options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Simply install the plugin for Eclipse:

[Eclipse Web Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0)

Then configure the HTML editor to not show the errors of the inserted python code.

[image]

[image]